# Outlook Shared Mailbox Property Change Event

Tags: vba, outlook

I am connecting to a shared mailbox in outlook but want to use a inspector/PropertyChange event on the mailitem .Subject so that when it is changed by someone it will send the details to sql server. I can already write the data into SQL or Excel etc using vba but I dont know how to do the event so that it runs the vba/script every time there is a saved change to the Subject.

I found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa171326(v=office.11)

Which talks about what I am trying to do but gives an example relating to the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in the [Items.ItemChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.itemchange) event which is fired when an item in the specified collection is changed. Also you may consider handling the [MailItem.PropertyChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.propertychange) event which is fired when an explicit built-in property (for example, Subject) of a `MailItem` object is changed.

The [Implement a wrapper for inspectors and track item-level events in each inspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-implement-a-wrapper-for-inspectors-and-track-item-level-events-in-each-inspector) article shows how to handle these events correctly.

Comment: Thanks for this but how do I convert it to VBA as the link you have included shows the code in c#? I will try and follow the same approach in vba and see how i get on and post my code once done and hopefully this will help.

Comment: The Outlook object model is common for all kind of programming languages.